# Extracting models from H2O AutoML leaderboard

Tags: r, h2o, automl

When I train a model in R using autoML, I can view the leaderboard of the models via

```
automl_model@leaderboard
```

and I can get access to the best model via

```
automl_model@leader
```

However, I want also make experiments with the 2nd best model, 3rd best model, and so on. How can I access them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to access models like this:

```
model_ids <- as.vector(automl_model@leaderboard$model_id)
index <- 2
model_2 <- h2o.getModel(model_ids[index])
```

, where `index` is a position of the model in the leaderboard.